# How do I name a selected group via python script?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, groups

I was wondering if anyone knows a simple python command that allows me to rename the selected group. I am working on a script that requires a renaming mid operator. I found one to rename the selected objects but not a group specifically.

Comment: If there is a group named "Group" then  `bpy.data.groups["Group"].name = "Frank"` will change its name to "Frank".  Not sure as to which is the active group guess is  `ob.users_group[0]`

Answer (score 2):

Using [`Object.users_group`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=users_group#bpy.types.Object.users_group) returns a list of all groups the object is assigned to. Decide which group of the list you'd like to rename and assign a new name to `GroupData.name` property.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
obj_group = next(iter(obj.users_group), None)

if obj_group:
    grp = bpy.data.groups.get(obj_group.name)
    grp.name += "_special"
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked but I used batfinger's method to do it in less lines of code. -Brad

Comment: In case you know the name of the group, that's fine @BradHamilton

Comment: No longer an orphan.